# Accessing json data passed in string form

Tags: javascript, json

I am passing data from php in json format, how do I access it?

This is the result:

```
{"solctype":"Long Term Agreement","checkbox":"1","prnumber":"356363563"}
```

I have tried

```
$.post("getgrid?id="+id,
{
},
function(data, status){
    console.log(data.solctype);

});
```

This always returns undefined

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the string data and convert it to a JavaScript object.

Use something like this:

```
    var stringData = {"solctype":"Long Term Agreement","checkbox":"1","prnumber":"356363563"};
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(stringData);
    console.log(parsedData.solctype)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse